# How to generate HTML output using Gradle FindBugs Plugin

Tags: html, gradle, findbugs

Using the [Gradle FindBugs Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/findbugs_plugin.html), how can I generate the output in HTML format??

The [FindBugsExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html) do have some config to set.

```
findbugs {
    toolVersion = "2.0.1"
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    visitors = ["FindSqlInjection", "SwitchFallthrough"]
    omitVisitors = ["FindNonShortCircuit"]
    includeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/includeFilter.xml")
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

But there is no **output** Properties to set as the findbugs anttask.

Comment: Where did you write this plugin? Is it in the project's `build.gradle` or module's `build.gradle`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Reports can only be configured on the `FindBugs` *tasks*. For example:

```
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

The same holds for the other code quality plugins (Checkstyle, PMD, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! Where can I find reference for this task? Is it stated somewhere in the official manual/reference?

Also, is it possible to set a style file for generating the html?

Comment: All tasks are documented in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html). Sometimes you'll have to follow the links to the Javadoc/Groovydoc. It isn't possible to set a style file.

Comment: I dont have any such section for "PMD" and I see both reports (.xml and .html). Can you please clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have such a section"? All you need to do is `tasks.withType(Pmd) { reports { ... } }`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967309/findbugs-android-gradle-plugin?

Comment: No html reports for checkstyle (Gradle 2.8) - https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/index.html?org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/CheckstyleReports.html