# Findbugs android gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, findbugs, gradlew

I have an android project. I want to introduce `findbugs` in my project as a gradle plugin. I tried to edit the project's `build.gradle` as below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
           }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "findbugs"
findbugs {
  toolVersion = "2.0.1"
  sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
  ignoreFailures = false
  reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
  effort = "max"
  reportLevel = "high"
  includeFilter =     file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/includeFilter.xml")
  excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
 }
```

Is this plugin correct?
 Does anything neeed to be added or removed?
Now what should I do to get the results of this `findbugs` check? 
What gradle command should I use?

Comment: Click sync now to update gradle

Comment: @sukumar Actually I want a command to invoke this as this is done as a part of continuous integration. Syncing is success. Zero errors and zero warnings. Does the plugin look alright.

Comment: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/static-code-analysis-automation-using-findbugs-android-studio/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just place this in your modules `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

task customFindbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "low"
    classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes")

    // Use this only if you want exclude some errors
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.rootDir/config/findbugs/exclude.xml")

    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    classpath = files()

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        xml.withMessages = true
        html.enabled = !xml.isEnabled()
        xml.destination "$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-output.xml"
        html.destination "$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-output.html"
    }
}

build.dependsOn customFindbugs
```

Then after changing directory to your project path from command line, use

```
./gradlew build
```

The error report will be in `$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-output.html`

Answer (score 10):

I modified a little bit Nevin Raj Victor's answer.

This version generates a findbug task for each build variant, and (more importantly) it correctly creates dependencies on their respective compilation tasks. Indeed, findbugs requires the code to be compiled before it can be analyzed.

```
// findbug tasks for each variant
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task("findbugs${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: FindBugs) {
        description "Analyze ${variant.name} code with the findbugs tool"
        group "Verification"

        ignoreFailures = true
        effort = "default"
        reportLevel = "medium"

        classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/${variant.dirName}")
        excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.rootDir/findbugs/findbugs-filter.xml")
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        classpath = variant.javaCompile.classpath

        reports {
            // Only one of HTML or XML can be turned on at the same time
            html.enabled = true
            xml.enabled = !html.enabled
            xml.withMessages = true

            html.destination = "$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-${variant.name}-output.html"
            xml.destination = "$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-${variant.name}-output.xml"
        }

        dependsOn "compile${variant.name.capitalize()}JavaWithJavac"
    }
}
```

After this, you can run

```
./gradlew findbugsDebug
./gradlew findbugsRelease
```

Or other findbugs tasks on different variants, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this project https://github.com/Piasy/AndroidCodeQualityConfig.

This project including lint, pmd, findbugs, checkstyle, jacoco code coverage.And support project with submodules.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your configuration:

- instead of `2.0.1` version use latest `3.0.1`
- set `reportLevel` to `low` instead of `high` to report all the violations
- for the first analysis you don't need to configure any `includeFilter` or `excludeFilter` - these are only whitelist and blacklists of checks if you need some customization

To run analysis just invoke `gradle findbugsMain`. Results should be visible in the output.

Comment: Kordas: The plugin seems to work fine now as `./gradlew findbugsMain` is being executed. But I can't find any log in the specified folder.

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing in `build/findbugsReports` directory?

Comment: Kordas: `build/findbugsReport` directory is not getting generated.

Comment: So probably you have nothing in `[sourceSets.main]`. Can you try running without `sourceSets` property or with different value there?

Comment: Kordas: Still no `build/findbugsReport ` folder is generated. What does the plugin expects in `sourceSets`. I have more than one modules in my project.

Comment: you can try something like `subprojects { apply plugin: 'findbugs' findbugs { toolVersion = '3.0.1' } }` and you should have report in `build\reports\findbugs\main.xml` for each module.

Comment: Kordas: How can we manually give value to `sourceSets` . The error is due to the invalid folder structure. My project is having an older folder structure.I tried `sourceSets = '$rootProject.projectDir/Module/res'`. But it gives me an error `Cannot cast object '$rootProject.projectDir/Module/res' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Collection'`

Comment: I tried with a project having single module named `app` and having latest folder structure. But still there is no `findbugsReport` . Is their any other solution. I printede the value of `sourceSets ` as `[[source set 'main']]`